# R - Aggregate and count instances of grouping

Tags: r, tidyverse

Dataset is a breakdown of responders and the number of contacts they have had within a given time period along with details on their age bracket, something similar to:

```
participant    participant_age      contact      contact_age
     1               18-30             1            18-30
     1               18-30             2            30-40
     2               30-40             1            18-30
     3               18-30             1            18-30
     3               18-30             2            50-60
```

My aim is to calculate the mean number of contacts each age group of participant has had with each age bracket of contact. Something similar to:

```
   age_bracket   18-30    30-40    40-50
      18-30        1        3        2
      30-40        1.5      4        2
      40-50        3        4        1
```

I have been attempting to use the group_by and spread functions available in dplyr. The closest I have come is using

```
data%>%
  group_by(participant_age, contact_age) %>%
  tally() %>%
  spread(key = participant_age, value = n)
```

But this produces the total number (n) of each contact, rather than the mean number of contacts per age bracket.

Comment: How do you get value as 3 for 30-40 column in 1st row?

Comment: Not actual data, just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R use `tapply`.

```
t(with(dat, tapply(contact, list(contact_age, participant_age), mean)))
#       18-30 30-40 50-60
# 18-30     1     2     2
# 30-40     1    NA    NA
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(participant = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L), participant_age = c("18-30", 
"18-30", "30-40", "18-30", "18-30"), contact = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L), contact_age = c("18-30", "30-40", "18-30", "18-30", 
"50-60")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your aim, you were pretty close to the right solution:

```
data %>%
 group_by(participant_age, contact_age) %>%
 summarise(mean = mean(contact), .groups = "drop") %>%
 spread(key = participant_age, value = mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_wider` and pass the function to apply in `values_fn` :

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = contact_age, values_from = contact, values_fn = mean)
```